# How to automatically sum input value boxes on each row in a HTML table

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML table with columns of input boxes (Quantity, Price, Discount and Total). I made a JS function for adding as many rows as I need. I would like to make the Total column, for each row, to display automatically the value of this formula:

(Quantity * Price) - ( Quantity * Price * (Discount/100)) .

I tried numerous JavaScript code, but I have been unable to get anything to correctly work.

HTML:

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<th width="65%"></th>
<th align="center" width="5%">Q<br>-ty</th>
<th align="center" width="10%">Price,</br>$</th>
<th align="center" width="5%">Discount,<br>%</th>
<th align="center" width="15%">Total, $<br>(Without tax)</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="65%"><input class="Left" size="100" type="text" name="Description"></td>
<td align="center" width="5%"><input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="99"></td>
<td align="center" width="10%"><input type="number" name="summ" min="0" max="999999"></td>
<td align="center" width="5%"><input type="number" name="rate" min="0" max="100"></td>
<td align="center" width="15%"><input align="center" type="number" name="total" min="0" max="99999999"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function addRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow();
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    cell1.innerHTML = "<input class=\"Left\" size=\"100\" type=\"text\" name=\"Description\">";
    cell2.innerHTML = "<div align=\"center\"><input type=\"number\" name=\"quantity\" min=\"1\" max=\"99\"></div>";
    cell3.innerHTML = "<div align=\"center\"><input type=\"number\" name=\"summ\"  min=\"0\" max=\"999999\"></div>";
    cell4.innerHTML = "<div align=\"center\"><input type=\"number\" name=\"rate\"  min=\"0\" max=\"100\"></div>";
    cell5.innerHTML = "<div align=\"center\"><input type=\"number\" name=\"total\" min=\"0\" max=\"99999999\"></div>";
}
```

[**My code on FIDDLE.**](http://jsfiddle.net/j8Lnt8w4/4/)

Comment: +1 for the well asked question. For your point I'd start by adding two classes to each input. One common to all of them so that I can run $('.class1').blur(function(){}); to trigger the update of the total.  The other is actually one for each input so that you can get it's value to apply your math. This assuming you can use jQuery.

Comment: Your problem is that there is no implementation of that formula on input change, row add.

Comment: jquery is tagged, but are you using it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j8Lnt8w4/8/ is this what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is little different example. I remove that `div` from Your js code.

```js
function calc(id) {
var row=id.parentNode.parentNode;
var quant=row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
var price=row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
var disc=row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
if(disc==null || disc=='') {
 res=parseFloat(quant)*parseFloat(price);
} else {
 var res=(parseFloat(quant)*parseFloat(price))-(parseFloat(quant)*parseFloat(price)*(parseFloat(disc)/100));
}
row.cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value=res;
   }
   function addRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow();
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
 var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
 var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
 var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    cell1.innerHTML = "<input class=\"Left\" size=\"100\" type=\"text\" name=\"Description\">";
    cell2.innerHTML = "<input onkeyup=\"calc(this);\" onchange=\"calc(this);\" type=\"number\" name=\"quantity\" min=\"1\" max=\"99\">";
 cell3.innerHTML = "<input onkeyup=\"calc(this);\" onchange=\"calc(this);\" type=\"number\" name=\"summ\"  min=\"0\" max=\"999999\">";
 cell4.innerHTML = "<input onkeyup=\"calc(this);\" onchange=\"calc(this);\" type=\"number\" name=\"rate\"  min=\"0\" max=\"100\">";
 cell5.innerHTML = "<input type=\"number\" name=\"total\" min=\"0\" max=\"99999999\">";
}
```

```css
 body {
    font-family: "Calibri"; margin:0;}

#inTotal {
 font-weight: bold;
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.nr {
 font-weight: bold;
}
input {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
 text-align: center;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.Left {
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
            
<th width="65%"></th>

<th align="center" width="5%">Q<br>-ty</th>
    
<th align="center" width="10%">Price,</br>$</th>

<th align="center" width="5%">Discount,<br>%</th>

<th align="center" width="15%">Total, $<br>(Without tax)</th>

</tr>
<tr>
<td width="65%"><input class="Left" size="100" type="text" name="Description"></td>
                
<td align="center" width="5%"><input onkeyup="calc(this);" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="99" onchange="calc(this);"></td>
                    
<td align="center" width="10%"><input onkeyup="calc(this);" type="number" name="summ" min="0" max="999999" onchange="calc(this);"></td>
                        
<td align="center" width="5%"><input onkeyup="calc(this);" type="number" name="rate" min="0" max="100" onchange="calc(this);"></td>
                            
<td align="center" width="15%"><input align="center" type="number" name="total" min="0" max="99999999"></td>
    
</tr>
                            
</table>
                        
 <button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
```

I add one more function for calculating Your formula on every change or number inputed.

That function is placed in every `input` expect last one (`onchange="calc(this)` and `onkeyup=calc(this);`). I put `onkeyup` on very beginning of `input`. In that case will make calucation after number is entered.

Code is, like You can see, only js.